# Traversing down through DOM tree

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function A(){

  var count=0;
   var A=0;
   var C=0;

   $('.JRow').each(function(){
     count++;

     alert(count);


      $this.$('.BtnSet').each(function(){
        A++;
        alert(A);

      $this.$('.Child').each(function(){
        C++;
        alert(C);

       if(('$(this) input:text[name="A[]"]').length){

       alert('$(this) input:text[name="A[]"]').length);
       }

         });

         });
});

    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return A()">
    <div class="row JRow">
     <input type="text" name="B[]"></input>
     <input type="text" name="B[]"></input>
        <div class="BtnSet">
            <div class="Child">

            </div>

            <div class="Child">
                <input type="text" name="A[]"></input>
                <input type="text" name="A[]"></input>
                <input type="text" name="A[]"></input>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
<div class="JRow"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, I need to traverse through this. If I start from JRow class the first JRow should search whether it has a BtnSet Class. If so, That BtnSet Class should search whether it has a Child Class. In my example, since first set of Btnset has 2 Child classes I need to go through each of them to get the final output which, the length of its textboxes. Likewise I need to go each and every node. When it comes to second JRow it doesn't have anything. My real question is so  complicated and I made a simple question through it. Please if anyone knows this help me since Im struggling with this for many days.

Comment: Could you be a bit brief and format your question ?

Comment: [How jQuery Works!](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Comment: Thanx alot. Will go through them to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `find()` function?  That will find matching descendants of the selected element(s).

Instead of `$this.$('.BtnSet')`, you probably want:

```
$(this).find( '.BtnSet')
```

Try also using intermediate variables, so you can log/ or debug your code. It's amazing how people don't bother to be able to see what's going on, and then wonder why they can't debug or figure out where their code is wrong.

Principle: if you can't log or inspect an intermediate step, and there is more than one step involved in the overall behavior, you will not be able to efficiently debug a failure in the overall behavior.

You will be reduced to grossly ineffective trial-and-error, which typically fails.

Instead of `if(('$(this) input:text[name="A[]"]').length){`, try debugging like:

```
var inputsAll = $(this).find( 'input');  // just for learning & debugging
var inputsA = $(this).find( 'input:text[name="A[]"]');
console.log('  found inputs', inputsAll, inputsA);
if (inputsA.length) {
```

You can't put a $(this) inside the selector. Selectors are a text expression, calling jQuery to select/ or wrap a DOM element is a Javascript function call. You can't magically inter-mangle them.

Comment: K thank you so much sir. Im really really new to JQuery. Still working to understand it . I'll go through what you said.

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is not correct `$(this)`

change

```
if(('$(this) input:text[name="A[]"]').length){
```

to

```
if ($(this).find('input:text[name="A[]"]').length) {
```

**you code becomes**

```
function A() {
    var count = 0;
    var A = 0;
    var C = 0;
    $('.JRow').each(function () {
        count++;
        alert(count);
        $(this).find('.BtnSet').each(function () {
            A++;
            alert(A);
            $(this).find('.Child').each(function () {
                C++;
                alert(C);
                if ($(this).find('input:text[name="A[]"]').length) {

                    alert(('$(this) input:text[name="A[]"]').length);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    return false;
}
```

if you just want to count length you can use

```
$('.JRow').length;
```

References

[.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

[How jQuery Works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) as commented by [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848164/undefined)

Updated after OP's comment

Use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('.JRow').has('.BtnSet');

$('.JRow > .BtnSet').has('.child');

$('.JRow > .BtnSet >.child').has('input:text[name="A[]"]');
```

Comment: I need to know whether a class has another class as a child. Most important thing is it should find the child of the selected class. that's why I used $(this) in each  part. Is the way I have used wrong?

Comment: `$('.JRow').has('.BtnSet');`, _"will return cool value i.e true of false"_, that's not true, it returns a filtered collection, it doesn't return s boolean value.

Comment: @undefined yeah was my mistake i already updated it

Comment: @Thushar: K thank you very much for your clear explanation. I'll go through them.